# Facebook chat plugin auto scrolls page to top when loaded

Tags: facebook, plugins, chat, messenger, autoscroll

I am using Facebook Chat plugin version 8.0 on a site powered by OpenCart (though I suspect it will happen in any CMS). It always takes a few seconds for the chat plugin to fully load and the icon to appear in the lower right corner of the page.

However, when the icon is displayed, the page immediately scrolls to the top. So if a user already started scrolling down, he is interrupted and the page is reset.

Any idea what might be causing this and how to prevent it?

This is my code (vanilla code auto generated by Facebook in Settings->Messaging->Add Messenger to your website):

```
<script>      

        FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v8.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  
</script>

        <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
        <div class="fb-customerchat"
            greeting_dialog_display="hide"
            attribution=setup_tool
            page_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            theme_color="#67b868">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is currently being tracked here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/619023102320436/.

At the moment I have implemented the following hack (around the load time of the plugin):

```
var originalScrollTo = window.scrollTo;
window.scrollTo = function() {};

setTimeout(function() {
 window.scrollTo = originalScrollTo;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Excellent temporary solution, this prevents the scrolling completely. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this behavior only happens on a PC web browser in Responsive Design Mode emulating a smartphone  (Tested on Chrome 84.0 and Firefox 79.0).

On an actual smartphone it doesn't scroll to the top.

Edit: I was mistaken, it does scroll to the top on my smartphone after all. Please see the temporary solution to this issue in the first answer.

Comment: Actually I have exact the same issue on desktop, mobile, and any other browser. So it's not your weird case. Also, I've seen this bug reported here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-scrolling-to-top-of-page-on-mobile-load/ and also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901856/messenger-chat-plugin-scrolls-to-top-on-load

Comment: You are right! Now it is also happening on my smartphone as well. Thanks for the links, hope they fix this soon.