# Messenger chat plugin scrolls to top on load

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger

When using hash parameters to automatically scroll the page to an anchor on page load, the messenger chat plugin automatically scrolls the page to the top if its load is delayed. This happens on my physical mobile device and in an emulator (Chrome). Is there any step required to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Also, mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63535349/facebook-chat-plugin-auto-scrolls-page-to-top-when-loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is currently being tracked here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/619023102320436/.

At the moment I have implemented the following hack (around the load time of the plugin):

```js
var originalScrollTo = window.scrollTo;
window.scrollTo = function() {};

setTimeout(function() {
 window.scrollTo = originalScrollTo;
}, 5000);
```